# Selected item Show In drop-down in Edit Case Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, html-select, dropdown

View Code Show the Drop Down In Client Side--

```html
<select ng-model="employee.DeptId" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="">
<option disabled="disabled" value="">---Please Select---</option>
 <option ng-repeat="Dep in ShowDep" value="{{Dep.Id}}">{{Dep.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Angular Code In Edit Case----

```html
$scope.EmployeeEdit = function (rowNumber) {
args = employeeArr[rowNumber];
$scope.employee.DeptId = args.DeptId;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-value instead of value in option tag.

```
<select ng-model="employee.DeptId" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="">
<option disabled="disabled" ng-value="">---Please Select---</option>
 <option ng-repeat="Dep in ShowDep" ng-value="{{Dep.Id}}">{{Dep.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

Not clear about the structure of the data your binding. 
So here I am showing your requirement with my own data. I think you could do the same in your cod also.

```
$scope.degrees = [
                   {"degree_code":"GB","degree_name":"Bachelor of Science"},
                   {"degree_code":"GR","degree_name":"Non Degree Undergraduate"}
                 ];
 $scope.selecteddegree = {degree_code:"GB"};

<!-- html -->
 <select name="degree" class="form-control" ng-model="selecteddegree" ng-options="degree.degree_name for degree in degrees track by degree.degree_code" >
           <option value=""> Select Degree </option>
 </select>
```